# No fullscreen button on YTPlayer toolbar iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using YTPlayer in my iOS app. Everything's fine until the fullscreen button on the toolbar of the YTPlayer got disappeared, now I don't see the fullscreen button, [image: YTPlayer without fullscreen button]

instead I have a video quality button, playlist button and play on youtube button which are not much useful for me, also which weren't there before. So how to get a fullscreen button on the toolbar and if possible how to remove unwanted buttons. Should I have to change anything in the html file?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; width:100%%; height:100%%; }
        html { width:100%%; height:100%%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script>
    var player;
    YT.ready(function() {
             player = new YT.Player('player', %@);
      window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onYouTubeIframeAPIReady';
    });
    function onReady(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onReady?data=' + event.data;
    }
    function onStateChange(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;
    }

    function onPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onPlaybackQualityChange?data=' + event.data;
    }
    function onPlayerError(event) {
        window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onError?data=' + event.data;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [David](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4941652/david) says: "On iPad, any embeded youtube videos are missing fullscreen button, starting from last week. "

Comment: this issue has now been resolved

Comment: Is there a way to go back to the way it was during the issue? I found it really cool to have that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. The fullscreen button is visible now. Have no idea why it disappeared and why it got back, think youtube modified it or something.